# Why can't you install operating system onto RAM

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, operating-systems

Why can't you install an operating system onto RAM?

I know RAM is temporary memory and this memory will be lost when the power is switched off so can't the computer like save the state of the operating system on the SSD/HDD and reload it back into RAM when the power is switched on?

Comment: What, like in *RAM Disk*?

Comment: It is possible, but windows wants >30+gb for the RAM drive and another 8+gb for active programs.  You are looking at nearly 64gb of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

> save the state of the operating system on the SDD/HDD and reload it back into RAM when the power is switched on

That's called hibernation.

I believe Windows in its normal booting process also doesn't actually reload from zero, but actually uses a RAM image that it created on the previous shutdown.

Comment: Your belief is incorrect.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: it's a system feature that's enabled by default called [Fast startup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/distinguishing-fast-startup-from-wake-from-hibernation). Perhaps "normal booting process" is a bit of an ambiguous term, but this is something that happens most of the time you boot your machine since Windows 8 unless there's a system update, hardware changes, or you disabled Fast startup.

Comment: I'm well aware of Fast Startup, and it is not what you described. With Fast Startup the kernel does not get shut down and reloaded and reinitialized at all -  it's left in its previous state in RAM, or else reloaded from the hibernate file, which was saved the last time you shut down (not just after updates or hardware changes). Only the user mode sessions are shut down and then restarted.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: Fair enough, I think you are probably correct. I've updated my answer to reflect my new belief.